# Add Structure Logging capabilities when using a custom log4net provider in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and I have created a custom logger provider MyLog4NetCustom that implements ILoggerProvider (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging).

In the Startup.cs I add this provider. Log is working and I see message in ELK stack.

Now I need to add structured Logging capabilities.

How this can be done?

Note: I saw there are other providers integrated with logging framework of ASP.NET Core that allow structured logging, but I need to use my custom log4net provider.

Thanks